# Quill font format is ignored

Tags: quill, parchment

I have the instance and the Quill editor. 
As well, i use custom fonts for my toolbar:

```js
Font.whitelist = ['roboto', 'roboto-mono'];
Quill.register(Font, true);
```

Then i use font roboto-mono for text. When i save the innerHTML from the .ql-editor I have something like this:

```html
<p><span class="ql-roboto-mono">asdkasdlas</span></p>
```

But when I insert it in the editor on refreshing page, I got the next result:
`<p>asdkasdlas</p>`
For inserting text I use `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML`. 
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1769) in Quill (in Parchment, in fact...).

Just provided a [fix](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/pull/40).

Comment: Good job, Mike. Thank you for your contribution